# python while loop for an entry of 2 integers seperated by delimiter

Tags: python

I need to be able to accept entries as 3,4 , basically 2 integers seperated by a comma. I need a while loop to keep asking for input until they input it in correct format as 2 numbers. this is my code so far

```
def main():
    try:
        move = [int(s) for s in input("Select a cell (row,col) > ").split(",")]
    except:
        while move != []#stuck here

    x = move[0]
    y = move[1]



main()
```

Comment: I assume you are getting an error. Share it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost have it. You just need to straighten out a few details. First, if the input fails, you want an empty input:

```
try:
    move = [int(s) for s in input("Select a cell (row,col) > ").split(",")]
except:
    move = []
```

Now you want to repeat the input until it is valid. You first need the syntax for a while loop:

```
while <condition>:
   <body>
```

Where `condition` evaluates to a boolean and `<body>` is the lines to repeat. In this case, you want to repeat the `try...except`.

```
def main():
    while move != []:
        try:
            move = [int(s) for s in input("Select a cell (row,col) > ").split(",")]
        except:
            move = []

    x = move[0]
    y = move[1]
```

When you get stuck on syntax issues like this, I suggest you read the documentation and tutorials at https://python.org. They explain how to correctly write a while loop or try...except and more.

Comment: UnboundLocalError raised because move isn't defined

Comment: What would I define move as before?

Comment: @Kamal Yup, I missed a detail. What can you initialize `move` to before the `while` loop so that you guarantee that it repeats at least once?

Comment: @SuperStormer Thanks for the comment. I'm going to let the OP think about how to fix my code for a while before I post the fix.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Got it! Thank you very much

Comment: @Kamal What solution did you come up with to fix the error in my code?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by this way:

```
def main():
  print('Enter the two points as comma seperated, e.g. 3,4')
  while True:
    try:
      x, y = map(int, input().split(','))
    except ValueError:
      print('Enter the two points as comma seperated, e.g. 3,4')
      continue
    else:
      break


main()
```

Comment: BTW the `strip` is not necessary. `int()` will do it alone. For example, `int("   3    ")` works just fine and returns the `int` 3

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thank you, I edited it. I did this mistake because I am used to read from files so that I wrote `strip()`

Comment: I don't think it's a mistake anyway... Just redundant and this way the code is just a bit more easy to read :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a nested function and a recursive call if the input doesn't conform to expectations.

```py
import re


def main():

    def prompt():
        digits = input("Select a cell (row,col) > ")
        if not re.match(r'\d+,\d+', digits):
            print('Error message')
            prompt()
        return digits.split(',')

    move = prompt()

    x = move[0]
    y = move[1]


main()
```